# Is there any way to upload video from ui component in magento2

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, video

I am working on a custom requirement where a user can upload video from a custom UI component but I can't find any way for that. if there any way to do this in magento2?

Comment: Hi there, by my guess magento is not providing to upload videos, except via youtube, you can try using javascript libraries for this.But the challenge is where will you display this video to the user? , If you need some kind of player to play this, you can choose one from the magento files like fotorama, or again go for any javascript libraries.Thanks

Comment: ok let me check on those..